# ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column

Tags: mysql

Am trying to execute a query. And it is throwing error.

I have a value given in the dictionary format which I need to give it a string for the query to execute. Even it is throwing an error.

Below is the query:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO wf_alti_scheduler_vijay (status,display_message,modified_on,exec_sequence,input_file_path,query_file_path,is_active,aws_destination_info,created_on,result_type,project,platform,scheduled_at,project_batch,frequency,output_file_path,env,next_schedule,kv_json,id,user) VALUES (-1.0,"test query","2016-10-24 13:15:35",1.0,"na","/home/viren/viru/workflow_dev/query/new_repeat_cust_current_month.sql",1.0,"na","2016-10-15 23:59:59","FILE","onyx_dev","HIVE","2016-10-15 23:59:59","onyx_monthly","monthly","/home/viren/viru/workflow_dev/op","dev","2016-11-15 23:59:59",{"QRY_PARAM_KEY_LIST": "PARAM_CURRENT_MONTH_START_DATE~PARAM_CURRENT_MONTH_END_DATE", "QRY_PARAM_VALUE_LIST": "20160901~20160930"},1.0,"virendhar");

ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column {"QRY_PARAM_KEY_LIST": "PARAM_CURRENT_MONTH_START_DATE~PARAM_CURRENT_MONTH_END_DATE", "QRY_PARAM_VALUE_LIST": "20160901~20160930"} in 'field list'
```

All the values are given using string format except the above. How to give it in string format to execute the query. Can someone help on this ?

Comment: post create table command please

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE wf_alti_scheduler_vijay`, and return back

Answer (score 0):

Whenever some json data is inputting to a column like the value `{"name":"kiran"}` try to input as `'{\"name\":\"kiran\"}'`.In your case the data

```
{"QRY_PARAM_KEY_LIST": "PARAM_CURRENT_MONTH_START_DATE~PARAM_CURRENT_MONTH_END_DATE", "QRY_PARAM_VALUE_LIST": "20160901~20160930"}
```

should be inputted as

```
'{\"QRY_PARAM_KEY_LIST\": \"PARAM_CURRENT_MONTH_START_DATE~PARAM_CURRENT_MONTH_END_DATE\", \"QRY_PARAM_VALUE_LIST\": \"20160901~20160930\"}'
```

Try this query

```
INSERT INTO wf_alti_scheduler_vijay (status,display_message,modified_on,exec_sequence,input_file_path,query_file_path,is_active,aws_destination_info,created_on,result_type,project,platform,scheduled_at,project_batch,frequency,output_file_path,env,next_schedule,kv_json,id,user) VALUES (-1.0,"test query","2016-10-24 13:15:35",1.0,"na","/home/viren/viru/workflow_dev/query/new_repeat_cust_current_month.sql",1.0,"na","2016-10-15 23:59:59","FILE","onyx_dev","HIVE","2016-10-15 23:59:59","onyx_monthly","monthly","/home/viren/viru/workflow_dev/op","dev","2016-11-15 23:59:59",'{\"QRY_PARAM_KEY_LIST\": \"PARAM_CURRENT_MONTH_START_DATE~PARAM_CURRENT_MONTH_END_DATE\", \"QRY_PARAM_VALUE_LIST\": \"20160901~20160930\"}',1.0,"virendhar")
```

If you are still getting any error then check the structure of your table and try again.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.7.8 supports a native JSON data type. So you can use that for above column.

Also add (') for start and end of json data as follows:

```
INSERT INTO wf_alti_scheduler_vijay (status,display_message,modified_on,exec_sequence,input_file_path,query_file_path,is_active,aws_destination_info,created_on,result_type,project,platform,scheduled_at,project_batch,frequency,output_file_path,env,next_schedule,kv_json,id,user) VALUES (-1.0,"test query","2016-10-24 13:15:35",1.0,"na","/home/viren/viru/workflow_dev/query/new_repeat_cust_current_month.sql",1.0,"na","2016-10-15 23:59:59","FILE","onyx_dev","HIVE","2016-10-15 23:59:59","onyx_monthly","monthly","/home/viren/viru/workflow_dev/op","dev","2016-11-15 23:59:59",'{"QRY_PARAM_KEY_LIST": "PARAM_CURRENT_MONTH_START_DATE~PARAM_CURRENT_MONTH_END_DATE", "QRY_PARAM_VALUE_LIST": "20160901~20160930"}',1.0,"virendhar");

For Eg:INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}');
```

Refer:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html